# xCode 4.2 UITableView drilldown

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I'm a newbie to the xCode world and I had a few questions regarding my application setup.
My application a list of Authors, click on author and get author detail plus book titles, and then click on the book title and get book information, but I'm unable to figure out the show detail part.

I have established a tab view controller that displays `UIViewControllers` in the window.

```
 //create view controllers
UIViewController *vc1 = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *vc2 = [[AuthorViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *vc3 = [[BooksViewController alloc] init]; 
UIViewController *vc4 = [[GenreViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *vc5 = [[UserViewController alloc] init];

//create instance of tab bar
self.tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
//add views to tab bar
self.tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2,vc3, vc4, vc5, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBar;

//self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
//self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[_window addSubview:_tabBar.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

This works perfectly. My first view "AuthorViewContoller" is a table and I can display data, however I can NOT get the detailController to show.

My AuthorViewController viewDidLoad method
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
self.author= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One", @"two", nil];

self.detailController = [[AuthorDetailController alloc] init];
```

and my methoddidSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    AuthorDetailController *dc = [[AuthorDetailController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AuthorDetailController" bundle:nil];

    dc.title = [author objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dc animated:YES];
}else{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
}
```

I'm declaring detailController in my AuthorViewController.h file.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet AuthorDetailController *detailController;
```

Comment: You've declared `detailController` as an IBOutlet, have you created it in IB and hooked it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually create a `UINavigationController`, and have it be part of your controller hierarchy, before you can use `pushViewController:animated:`.  You should really try setting this up in a NIB, instead of code, but in your code you can try this in place of your current `vc2` initialization:

```
UIViewController *vc2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[AuthorViewController alloc] init]];
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, you are the man, that was IT! I haven't gotten into the next view, but I want another list that functions exactly the same way, anything special i need to be aware of?

Comment: Since I don't know anything about the next view, I can't say.

Comment: well my next view is exactly like the first. The AuthorsController shows a list of authors (first view), the first drilldown is to see author bio and books (second view), now I want to drill into the books and show the book detail (third view). I'm guessing it's very similar setup?

Comment: You only need one navigation controller per tab.  Your AuthorViewController can create the bio/books controller and push it without creating another navigation controller.  The bio/books controller can create the book detail controller and push it without creating another navigation controller.